# Google OAUTH2 403 error in ios safari standalone webapplication

Tags: google-signin

I'm trying to get google sign in working in my web application using their JavaScript api.

```
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    // Sign the user in, and then retrieve their ID.
    auth2.signIn().then(function () {
        onGoogleSuccess(auth2.currentUser.get());
    });
```

It works great in safari, but I get a 403 disallowed_useragent if the user has added my app to their home screen (standalone mode).

Is there any way to get around the new security restrictions? this seems like an oversight for web applications

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  We are having the same issue with our web app.